# SonarQube showing wrong information from clearcase "Blame"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I configured a project in SONAR(6.1) to run from jenkins and configured to use clearcase as scm.

sonar.scm.provider=clearcase

And our clearcase is configured to use Local and Tst Streams.

Now when i checkout and checkin any changes into Local Stream for the first time it creates new branch for the changes .

When i checked the clearcase annotate(BLAME) information, its showing up correctly. But in SONAR it is showing incorrect.

Here is the information from annotate

0 **sgadey01** \main\FW_3.0.0.0_TST\FW_3.1.2.0_TST\FW_3.1.2.0_LOCAL\1                                               |                         |                 System.out.println("testing");

and information from SONAR as in the below link with user **bdiaz**.

https://s28.postimg.org/8m8l921rh/sonarerror.png

Is there any known limitation with sonar? for cvs plugin they mentioned revision has to be passed manually in limitations(https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scm-cvs).

Thanks
sandy

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube ClearCase SCM Provider is simply running cleartool annotate from command line and parsing output (see https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/scm/clearcase/ClearCaseBlameCommand.java) so I'm really surprised you get different results.

You can try to restart analysis and force the SonarQube scanner to collect blame again (there is a cache to not compute blame on files were content was not changed compared to previous analysis):

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.scm.forceReloadAll=true
```

Comment: Thanks Julien for the quick reply. I did forceReload, but no use. Also what i see is when a new Activity is done after creating a Branch , it is taking HEAD revision .But after then any new Activity is getting correct details. As sonar-scm-cvs has sonar.cvs.revision(https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scm-cvs), do we have something for sonar-scm-clearcase??

Comment: adding more example , below 2 lines are from clearcase annotate command. Both the versions are **1** but Branch is different. So ideally second line should show under **USER:sgadey01** but it was showing under **USER:tmoteka01**.

 

VERSION:1@@@USER:tmoteka01@@@DATE:20160801.180252@@@                try { 
VERSION:1@@@USER:sgadey01@@@DATE:20170105.093730@@@                        System.out.println("test");

Comment: Julien , is it possible to change the cleartool annotate VERSION to use **Vn** instead of **Ln** in [class](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/scm/clearcase/ClearCaseBlameCommand.java) for while formatting -fmt

Comment: Julien, After i modify the class to format version with Vn instead of Ln , my issue got fixed [screenshot](https://i.imgsafe.org/ec5bb0b313.png)  and the code change is  line 108 of [class](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/scm/clearcase/ClearCaseBlameCommand.java)   format.append("VERSION:%Vn@@@"); of class

Comment: @sandy Can you submit a pull request? We are no more officially supporting this plugin, so we are relying on community support.